# A story where the female main character commits suicide in order to avoid torture but gets sent back in time

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, manga

This is a novel that has a manga adaptation, and I read the first few chapters of the manga a few months ago, back in February. It was in full colour, I think.

The main character is accused of something (either attempted or successful murder), and she's sent to jail. She also believes her father either hates or is indifferent to her.

Before entering the jail, her father gives her a dagger/short sword, but she doesn't understand why. While in jail, she believes she's going to get tortured, and a knight with his (her?) face covered by their helmet enters, appearing very menacing. Seeing this as a confirmation of her fears, she commmits suicide with the weapon her father gave her, much to the knight's surpise.

She wakes up in the past, determined to change this future from happening, while also discovering that her father does care for her, much to her confusion.

It is also revealed that her father found her shortly after her suicide in the original timeline, and he was devastated, and it was hinted that he intended to save her somehow.

My apologies that it's so vague, this is all that I can remember.

Comment: Is this a short story or a novel? If it's a short story can you remember where you read it e.g. in an anthology or a magazine? Also when did you read it? The date you read it helps us pin down the publication date.

Comment: @Devanor - Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the man character's hair?

Comment: @LogicDictates It was in full colour, I think, but I can't remember what her hair was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while of searching, I finally found it! It was called *[Father, I Don't Want This Marriage](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/father-i-dont-want-this-marriage)* (not the most inspiring titles...)

> Juvelian is a villainess so hated by everyone that even her lover and father leave her to die a pitiful death. Just as she’s about to face her fate, she gets the chance to change the course of her story. In order to avoid the tragic end she knows awaits her, she breaks up with her lover and gives up trying to win her father’s love. Instead, she focuses on using his wealth to enjoy her new life to its fullest! But while she prepares for her extravagant life as a lady, her father begins looking for her new suitor. Afraid that he’ll marry her off to the infamously unpredictable and stormy prince, she lands on a desperate solution: a dating contract. And the best candidate is none other than her father’s student.

[This review](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/father-i-dont-want-this-marriage/reviews#77758) covers a few more points:

> The story is about a girl who reincarnates / isekais as Jubelian, the daughter of the duke and the villainess in a novel she'd read. What's worse, is that the villainess commits suicide after being abandoned by her love and father for an attempted poisoning.

Comment: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. As a self-answer, you have to wait 40 hours after asking, but it will let you know how long you have left if you click early.